# How to demo the push capabilities in iOS Bluelist Sample App (imf-bluelist)?

Tags: ios, ibm-cloud

I am using this sample application on IBM bluemix.
https://hub.jazz.net/project/mobilecloud/imf-bluelist/overview

I am able to receive push notifications on the device. I sent the notification with `TODO_CATEGORY` and also I accepted the notification, but I would like to know what should happen when you accept the notification. Is it supposed to add the message to the TODO List? Is it not getting added to the list.

Also how do you subscribe to notifications with tags? I created few tags on Bluemix and the list of tags are showing on the settings page, but it is not clear how to subscribe to tags.

Answer (score 2):

When you accept the notification, there is not currently functionality to add the message to the todo list.  For this sample, you could imagine that you've subscribed to push notifications from your favorite grocery store and they send you notifications about coupons or sales they're having based on the items in your grocery list.  As an extension to this app, you could easily pull in the information from the push notification and add it to the todo list.

To subscribe to notifications with tags, you first need to enable the notifications by sliding the on/off slider to on, and then you are able to click on each of the tags to subscribe.  You should see a check mark appear next to the tag once you've selected it.

There's a couple of great videos & articles around setting up the sample, using the sample, and how it all connects up to Bluemix here:

[Build an iOS 8 App with Bluemix and the MobileFirst Platform for iOS](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/mo-mfp-ios8-app/) (developerWorks how-to)

[Bluemix MobileFirst Platform for iOS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l0_0eV2B_NA) (15 minute walkthru on YouTube)